# Union-like column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is it possible in MySQL to have a column shared with 2 or more rows, like the C++ union type?
Is what I am looking for possible without more space and performance hit?

Comment: You want what? Explain more.

Comment: Can I ask why you need multiple values in one column instead of just putting them in multiple columns?

Comment: If the value of one column refers to a row of another table (through a foreign key relationship), all rows column-values of one table can share the same value of another table.

Comment: I have 2 rows. In those 2 rows I want them to share one column, like the c++ union type

Comment: As i understood you want to create a kind of "rowspan" ?

Comment: @We'reAllMadHere When you explain something a second time and use the same words as the first time, it usually doesn't help much. Also I'd say that the most users with much mysql experience not necessarily have any clue about C++.

Comment: When transfering C++ unions to SQL, you'd rather have a column which contains multiple values and not sharing columns between rows.

Comment: I have a table many rows. Each row got 5 columns. Now, I want rows #1 and #2 share column #1. When I say share I mean: a) if the value is altered in one, it will change for the other. b) The space will not be double.

Comment: Why you just don't use references ?

Comment: Because it will need additional searches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing as "C++ union type" is better explained in your comment:

> I have a table many rows. Each row got 5 columns. Now, I want rows #1 and #2 share column #1. When I say share I mean: a) if the value is altered in one, it will change for the other. b) The space will not be double.

What you are describing is the most basic part of a database: normalization and relational data.

You have table Countries:

```
ID=1, countryname="Amurika"
```

And cities:

```
ID=1,countryid=1, cityname="Boston"
ID=2,countryid=1, cityname="New York"
ID=3,countryid=1, cityname="Boise"
```

When you want to get your records you do:

```
SELECT cities.name, countries.countryname
FROM cities INNER JOIN countries on countries.id = cities.countryid
```

You get records:

```
name        countryname
------      -----------
Boston      Amurika
New York    Amurika
Boise       Amurika
```

You will note that "Amurika" is stored in only one place, and if you update it once:

```
UPDATE countries SET countryname="America" where id=1
```

You now get:

```
name        countryname
------      -----------
Boston      America
New York    America
Boise       America
```